# I don't understand the structure in this Steve Jobs sentence "Our hardware team got to cranking out a new Mac"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Steve Jobs said "[Our hardware team got to cranking out a new Mac with Intel processors every month](http://www.european-rhetoric.com/analyses/ikeynote-analysis-iphone/transcript-2007/)".

See [his video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7EfxMOElBE)

I think he wanted to say "....**had to crank out**..."

> **have to (modal verb)** (also have got to) used to show that you must do something. E.g: Sorry, I've got to go.

but why not "**got to crank out** " but "**got to cranking out**" ?

"have to doing something" is not right?

Comment: No, he said exactly what he wanted to say. It's idiomatic English. "Got to [VERB]ing" here means "eventually progressed to the point of habitually [VERB]ing". It has nothing to do with the modal _have to_.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, show me the evidence of idiom of "**Got to Ving**"

Comment: See the **[Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+to)** entry for _get to_, which tells you: "**2.** Begin doing something or start to deal with something. For example, _We got to reminiscing about college days_, or _Let's get to this business right now._ [Mid-1800s]". You will find many similar entries if you consult English language dictionaries for this very common usage. (Also, you might consult the English dictionary of your choice for a definition of the English adjective _"polite"_.)

Comment: @Tom: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22got%20to%20thinking%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: Also, Tom, Steve J is describing a *past* event, not a present obligation, and we don't use **got to** (in the sense of "must") with the past; it expresses the idea of present obligation (extending into the future). *Sorry, I gotta go*, *Sorry, I've got to go.* I must leave now. *I've gotta go to the DMV tomorrow.*, *I have got to go to the DMV tomorrow*.

Answer (score -1):

It might be more understandable this way:

> Our hardware team got **around** to cranking out a new Mac with Intel processors every month.

Meaning that the time finally arrived when they could take the actions described. See [*around*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/around):

> 1g. *adverb*
>   in succession or sequence - *his turn came around*